# Error while parsing XML: List Indices must be Integers or Slices, not Str

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, parsing

I am using `untangle` to convert XML files into readable python objects:

```
untangler = untangle.parse(fileDir)

untangler.project.matrixs.matrix['num'] # '1'
```

The XML file addressed:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project>
 <matrixs>
  <matrix num="1">
   <height>1920</height>
   <width>1080</width>
   <layout>across-back</layout>
   <notes>N/A</notes>
 </matrix>
</project>
```

However, when I run this code (which is nearly unmodified from the documentation) I recieve the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aaron/Documents/MatrixKontrol/src/saveparser.py", line 24, in <module>
    saveparser()
  File "/home/aaron/Documents/MatrixKontrol/src/saveparser.py", line 19, in saveparser
    untangler.project.matrixs.matrix['num'] # '1'
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I understand that this kind of list should normally not accept strings, but this works in all other examples I have seen online. Any help you can provide would be appreciated!

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Nearly unmodified... Just placed in my own variable names. I don't know why it would be a list in this instance, the parse syntax is exact.

Comment: Apologies, I stand corrected. *Your code works on my machine* (after fixing your typos in the XML so please check that). Python 3.6, brand new fresh install of `untangle` (v1.1.1). The type is `untangle.Element` and apparently it *does* support this type of indexing.

Comment: .. does `print (untangler.project.matrixs.matrix)` print the expected data? It lists your `num` as an attribute?